# Your advice on a Hadoop MapReduce job

Tags: join, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have 2 files stored on a HDFS filesystem:

- tbl_userlog: `<website url (non canonical)> <tab> <username> <tab> <timestamp>`

  - example: www.website.com, foobar87, 201101251456
- tbl_websites: `<website url (canonical)> <tab> <total hits>`

  - example: website.com, 25889

I have written an Hadoop sequence of jobs which joins the 2 files on the website, performs a filter on the amount of total hits > n per website and then counts for each user the amount of websites he has visited which has > n total hits. The details of the sequence are as following:

1. A Map-only job which canonicizes the url in tbl_userlog (i.e. removes www, http:// and https:// from the url field)
2. A Map-only job which sorts tbl_websites on the url
3. An identity Map-Reduce job which takes the output of the 2 previous jobs as KeyValueTextInput and feeds them to a CompositeInput in order to make use of Hadoop native joining feature defined with `jobConf.set("mapred.join.expr", CompositeInputFormat.compose("inner" (...))`
4. A Map and Reduce job which filters the result of the previous job on total hits > n in its Map phase, groups the results on the  in the shuffling phase, and performs the count on the number of websites for each user in the Reduce phase.

In order to chain these steps, I just call the jobs sequentially in the described order. Each individual job outputs its results into HDFS which the following job in the chain then retrieves and processes in turn.

As I am new to Hadoop, I would like to ask for your counseling:

1. Is there a better way to chain these jobs? In this configuration all intermediate results are written to HDFS and then read back.
2. Do you see any design flaw in this job, or could it be written more elegantly by making use of some Hadoop feature that I have missed?

I am using Apache Hadoop 0.20.2 and using higher-level frameworks such as Pig or Hive is not possible in the scope of the project.

Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: What's the intent of the Algorithm? Is it to find the number of websites each user visited, given that the website has > n number of total hits? Also, can you clarify what the question is supposed to be? Are you looking for a workflow management tool (like oozie, suggested by another poster) or are you looking for validation of your particular workflow?

Comment: @Pradeep Gollakota : Yes the goal of the job is to find for each user the amount of websites that he has visited which has total hits > n. I am not looking for any management tool (although I will give a look at Oozie, which seems promising), I am only looking for a validation of my particular workflow and design. My question in particular is: How would you have designed this workflown using _only plain Hadoop_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you have will work with a couple of caveats. Before I start listing them, I want to make two definitions clear. A map-only job is a job that has a defined Mapper and run's with 0 reducers. If the job is running with > 0 IdentityReducers, then the job is not a map-only job. A reduce-only job is a job that has a define Reducer and run's with an IdentityMapper.

1. Your first job, can be a map-only job, since all you're doing is canonicalizing URLs. But if you want to use CompositeInputFormat, you should run with an IdentityReducer with more than 0 reducer's.
2. For your second job, I don't know what you mean by a map-only job that sorts. Sorting by it's very nature is a reduce side task. You probably mean that it has a define Mapper but no Reducer. But in order for the URLs to be sorted, you should run with an IdentityReducer with more than 0 reducer's.
3. Your third job is an interesting idea, but you have to be careful with CompositeInputFormat. There are two conditions that must be met for you to be able to use this input format. The first is that there has to be the same number of files in both input directories. This can be achieved by setting the same number of reducer's for Job1 and Job2. The second condition is that the input files CANNOT be splittable. This can be achieved by using a non splittable compression such as bzip.
4. This job sounds good. Although you can filter website that have < n hits in the reducer of the previous job and save yourself some I/O.

There's obviously more than one solution to a problem in software, so while you're solution would work, I wouldn't recommend it. Having 4 MapReduce jobs for this task is a bit expensive IMHO. The implementation I have in mind is a M-R-R workflow that uses Secondary Sort.

Comment: Hello @Pradeep and thank you for your detailed explanation. I have spent some time rethinking about the job and have come up with a solution with 2 Map+ _r_ IdentityReducers jobs (one for canonicizig url and sorting users, and one for filtering websites on total hits and sorting) and 1 Map+Reduce job with CompositeInputFormat.

I am interested in your M-R-R + Secondary Sort implementation, could you detail it a bit further?

Answer (score 0):

As far as chaining jobs is concerned, you should have a look at Oozie, which is a workflow manager.  I have yet to use it, but that's where I'd start.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will give a look at Oozie. But my requirement is to implement this workflow using plain Hadoop. Do you see any optimization that can be made?